# How can I merge 2 sheets in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have to update a defect database in excel that is filled with data that fluctuates between 160 to 700 rows every day. This database has 19 columns, some of which are numerical and some are descriptions codes or dates but the unique identifier would be the first column which holds an ID number.

I need to be able to merge an older version of the spreadsheet with a newer one and have the new sheet get rid of duplicate defects by ID and all other columns I only need to the new sheet to keep 4 columns with new data like status, priority, a second and third prioritization numbers.

I think I can do it by `Vlookup` but I am having trouble getting it to work correctly because of the different data types and some fields left blank because they will be filled in by supervisors.

How can I accomplish this? I would also be willing to try other ways if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It would be very helpful if you shared how the data is laid out and what formula you tried. We can then give you specific help.

Comment: If the defect is there on the older version, but it's not there on the newer version then I assume you do not want it kept, as the defect would be closed?
Also is a date field updated in the newer version... ie if you have a defect in the old sheet, and a defect in the newer sheet, is it always the newer sheet defect you want to keep?

Comment: You should really be using a database.

Answer (score 0):

**vlookup** seems like a great option to look up the information you need especially if you have a unique identifier.
If the data types are different then you can try using the **value()** function to convert text to a numerical value or text() function to do the reverse. If there are extra spaces of either side then trim() might do the trick.
The easiest way to get ride of duplicates is perhaps using **conditional formatting to highlight the duplicate values.** Then you can use **auto-filter** to filter **by color** and identify the duplicates; then perhaps sort and delete.

That's the best answer having limited information. If you would like more specific solutions then please be more specific with the issues you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  It has an Append command that will combine the rows from two separate sources into a single table:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/append-queries-HA104149760.aspx

Power Query has many other transformation functions to massage your data along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column on the old version.  The cell in each row will contain a lookup of the ID in that row against the ID list in the new version and create a flag if it is not a duplicate. Say the ID is in Col A; for row 2:

```
    = isna(match(A2,new_version_sheet_ID_range,0))
```

Make the range reference to the new version absolute (dollar signs).  Copy the formula down for all of the rows on the old version.  Any IDs that are not duplicates will be True.

Do an [Advanced Filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP010073942.aspx) on the flags and copy to the end of the entries in new version.  Delete the unwanted columns within the copied array.  Then move the four columns you need to the appropriate spreadsheet column.  If the columns you need are not easily identifiable, first copy the column headings to the new version at the end of the data, then copy the filtered data.  Delete the heading row after you have cleaned up the extra columns.